# Mute built in iPhone Microphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio

I have a Voice over IP application and I just want to be able to mute the built in microphone on a button click. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to mute the microphone, do you?  Just stop processing the incoming audio.  It's not something the SDK needs to do for you, it's something you need to do.

Comment: While this is indeed the correct answer, your answer is very much akin to "But why do the easy thing when this more complicated thing will solve your problem?"

Comment: @MikeyWard Not only that, but some people might use a library that doesn't have that functionality (like webrtc)