# control built in microphone volume in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, avaudiosession

I am implementing a VOIP application where I want to mute the microphone for some time. For your information, I don't want to stop processing outgoing audio.How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mute built in iPhone Microphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798146/mute-built-in-iphone-microphone)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSError *error;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setInputGain:0.0f error:&error];
```

- (BOOL)setInputGain:(float)gain
             error:(NSError * _Nullable *)outError
  Changes the input gain to the specified value.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/setInputGain:error: